# Fade drawn sprite - LibGdx

Tags: android, libgdx, sprite

I am using LibGdx for android game development. In a screen i want to fade an image after some time. My Code:

```
batcherGame = new SpriteBatch();

batcherGame.setProjectionMatrix(cam.combined);

 ...

batcherGame.begin();

 ... // Other elements drawn

hitSprite = new Sprite(injuries.getHitImage(), 0, 0, 136, 80);

hitSprite.setColor(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, .5f);

hitSprite.draw(batcherGame);

batcherGame.end();
```

No error comes when i execute this code but the image is not drawn on the display, kindly help.

Thanks

Comment: is the camera position is being updated? Also check the texture region being drawn

Comment: Do other elements draw fine? If so can you include that code as well?

Comment: Many things can go wrong. Better start with some working example (I used that drops/bucket one) and then change it step by step.

Comment: All other elements draw fine except this...
When i use this code : batcherGame.draw(injuries.getHitImage(), 0, 0, 136, 80) the image gets drawn but as i have to change the alpha of this particular image i am using a different sprite to draw it